# Need Help Create a Structure which Will be Send via UDP

Tags: c++, qt, networking, udp

I'm using Qt to create my application.
On my GUI, there's some button

1. QPushButton
2. QDial
3. QSlider

I want to send the state of my button on a QUdpSocket.

The "message" need to look like :

```
 int : nb_message
 bool stateOfMyQPushButton[32]
 int stateOfMyQDial[8]
 float stateOfMyQSlider[8]
```

I can use Qt to send my message, but my message need to not use Qt tools (c++ only). (Because the receiver of my message can't use Qt)

I need help to create the "structure" of my message. 
A friend told me that `union` could help me but I don't know how it works...